# How do I change the content of a collection view cell without tapping it in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, mobile-development

So I have a collection view with 12 cells. I initially set the content of all these 12 cells with an image. Without the user tapping the cells, I am wondering how I can change the content of any of these cells. I know there is didSelectItemAtIndexPath but I expect I can make a change here only after user interaction with this cell but what I want to do here is a little different. Thanks in advance and will appreciate very helpful responses.

Comment: Share your implementation where you set your cells image. Hopefully you did not do this via interface builder. CollectionViews work pretty much similar to TableViews.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a timer and reload the relevant cells when it fires?

You can either reload all cells using `reloadData` or reload a section or sections or even individual cells.

Also, you can perform batch updates where you simultaneously remove and insert and move cells but this sounds a bit over the top for what you want, but worth looking at.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot. ReloadData definitely helped and gave me the idea. The exact command I ended using was       `if( (index >= 0) && (index <= [_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]) ){
        [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]];} completion:nil];
    }` Just had to ensure the index was always in range of the number of items in the collection view or it will break the code. This code was in a public method I made so the check is very important

Comment: Great stuff ... since you *only* reload I don't think it is required to wrap it inside a batch update but what the heck that way you are ready if in future you want something more complex.